# Set input default date format for dates in a model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

There is a way to set the default date format of *input* dates in a model?

I need to create a model with data received in JSON format and date are formatted as `Y-m-dTH:i:sP`, but date in the DB are stored in the default `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. I added all the date fields in the `$dates` property of the model, but now when i create the model setting all the params in the constructor, like this:

```
$model = new Model($params);
```

I get a Carbon conversion error (`InvalidArgumentException`) because it tries to create a `Carbon` object from the `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.

I know [Date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), but if i set

```
protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP";
```

it creates the Carbon object correctly but i get an error while storing in the DB, because it tries to store the record with that format.

Is there a standard way to achieve what I need without converting the date format on each date param?

Comment: just call the to `toDateTimeString()` so it is a string and not an object?

Answer (score 0):

```
//date format = Y-m-dTH:i:sP
$date = '2011-09-16T11:38:23-05:00';
$new_date = date_format(date_create($date), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This isn't a default, i have to repeat the code for every fields that is a date